# Perl -Database-Connection Count/error handling

Tags: perl, dbi

Using a perl script (Perl 5.8.6), I'm connecting to Sybase dataserver.

Looking for the following:

1. How many connections are currently opened by the script.
2. Generic (non-dataserver specific) Error handling modules/mechanism

When executing a stored proc, it returned the following error message.

> DBD::Sybase::st execute failed: Server
>   message number=27000 severity=16
>   state=1 line=4 server=SYBDEV_HYD
>   procedure=j_err text=But this one does
>   [for Statement "EXEC sandbox..j_err"]
>   at
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/DBIx/ContextualFetch.pm
>   line 51.

Since the user of this script is a non-techie, trying to report only the message "But this one does" (that appears after the text=). Though I can parse this, trying to see if there is any generic module, since other dataserver (like MySQL, SQL Server etc.) can have their own way of reporting the error msg.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but you'll find a lot of information by reading through the documentation for [DBD::Sybase](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Sybase/) and [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm).  You probably have to keep track of the number of connections yourself (see the example for [DBI->connect](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.609/DBI.pm#connect)).

For error-handling, you should probably just compose a reasonable diagnostic message yourself along with a line number - you can do this easily with [warn()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) or [carp()](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html).

Please also feel free to edit your question with more specifics about what you are trying to do; some sample code would be helpful.